# tracking utm campaign params with mixpanel as people properties

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

Here's my little javascript, which will save utm params into people properties. Really useful for filtering, which user was acquired by a specific marketing channel.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code after you initialize mixpanel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getQueryStrings() { 
  var assoc  = {};
  var decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, " ")); };
  var queryString = location.search.substring(1); 
  var keyValues = queryString.split('&'); 

  for(var i in keyValues) { 
    var key = keyValues[i].split('=');
    if (key.length > 1) {
      assoc[decode(key[0])] = decode(key[1]);
    }
  }
  return assoc;
}

var params = getQueryStrings();
for(var i in params) {
    var match = /utm_[a-z]+/
    if (match.test(i)) {
        var value = params[i];
        mixpanel.people.set_once(i, value);
    }
}
</script>
```